# is a "table page" something like an imaginary row or something?

Tags: sql-server, database

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-SQL-Server:

> The size for a table page is 8,196 bytes, and no one row in a table
>   can be more than 8,060 characters. This in turn limits the maximum
>   size of a VARCHAR to 8,000 bytes.

What exactly is a "table page"?

is a "table page" something like an imaginary row or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link for an explanation: [Understanding Pages and Extents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969.aspx)
Quote:

> The fundamental unit of data storage in SQL Server is the page. The
>   disk space allocated to a data file (.mdf or .ndf) in a database is
>   logically divided into pages numbered contiguously from 0 to n. Disk
>   I/O operations are performed at the page level. That is, SQL Server
>   reads or writes whole data pages.

Here's another one: [SQL Server data structures](http://blogs.developpeur.org/raptorxp/pages/sql-server-data-structures.aspx)
Quote:

> In SQL Server, data is organized in pages. A page has a fixed size (8
>   KB). Each page contains records. The number of records that can be
>   stored in a page depends on the size of the records. The operation of
>   reading data from a page is called a logical IO. The smaller the size
>   of a record is, the more records can be read with the same number of
>   logical IOs.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a unit of space that the database engine uses internally to manage the database. Typically a database engine will read a database one page at a time. Some db engines thus say that a single record cannot cross two pages, or have other such restrictions. 99% of the time you don't even think about this when creating a database. There's a maximum size on a row in the table. Exactly what internals lead to that maximum aren't really very important to the typical database programmer.